# Python data json dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, namedtuple

I wanted to read tar.json [file](https://easyupload.io/et92sy), so I write:

```
import json
with open('tar.json', "r", encoding='utf-8') as read_file:
          data = json.load(read_file)
```

and print it as dictionary, for which the key will be "linia" (written as int) and the value will be value tuple.

For example, for "linia 52" I want to get data in format:

```
{52: ('Czerwone Maki P+R', 'Chmieleniec', 'Kampus UJ', 'Ruczaj', 'Norymberska', 'Grota-Roweckiego', 'Lipińskiego', 'Kobierzyńska', 'Słomiana', 'Kapelanka', 'Szwedzka', 'Rondo Grunwaldzkie', 'Orzeszkowej', 'Stradom', 'Starowiślna', 'Poczta Główna', 'Teatr Słowackiego', 'Lubicz', 'Rondo Mogilskie', 'Cystersów', 'Białucha', 'TAURON Arena Kraków Wieczysta', 'Muzeum Lotnictwa', 'AWF', 'Stella-Sawickiego', 'Czyżyny', 'Rondo Czyżyńskie', 'Os. Kolorowe', 'Plac Centralny im. R.Reagana', 'Os. Zgody', 'Rondo Kocmyrzowskie im. Ks. Gorzelanego', 'DH Wanda', 'Rondo Hipokratesa', 'Dunikowskiego', 'Kleeberga', 'Piasta Kołodzieja')}
```

How to do this? And how to find for every key number of values tuples?

I know that command: `>>> data["linia"][19]["przystanek"][1]["name"]`

returns

```
'Chmieleniec 02'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It looks like the value of key `linia` is a list of dictionaries. You probably want to *iterate* over those entries, formatting them as appropriate. "Iterate" means "you need a loop of some sort".

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need.

```
import json
with open('tar.json', "r", encoding='utf-8') as read_file:
          data = json.load(read_file) 
          out = dict()
          for item in data['linia']:
            keys = list(item.keys())
            x = []
            for i in item[keys[1]]:
                x.append(i['name'])
            out[item[keys[0]]] = x
            print(out)
```

Comment: Additional note there are trailing digits in every name; like 01 02 etc. if you want to remove them instead of appending i['name'] directly make the necessary changes and then append.

Comment: I get an error:  `line 8, in <module>
    for i in item[keys[1]]:
IndexError: list index out of range `

Comment: This is probably because one item in your List of dicts not having any corresponding name_list in the dictionary. To counter this you can just put a conditional to check if keys has 2 items. ```if Len(keys) < 2: continue```

Comment: Now it don't return error but it print with repetitions, i. e. it firstly print "linia 1:", then "linia 1:", "linia 3:" and so on, instead of printing all "linia 1:", "linia 3:", ... at once.

Comment: The dictionary should contain "linia" 's number as key in format int.

Comment: Unindent print(out). I printed out because you needed that as the output according to question. Instead of printing out['1']. Out's format is dict. You just have to index to extract the output you need. Hope you have some understanding about python dict data structure.

Comment: what you see is it's always printing 1 is because it's always printing the whole out dict starting from first key which is '1'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248997/discussion-between-spramuditha-and-malum-phobos).

Comment: How to print  "linia 1:", "linia 3:", ... at once, without repetition?

Comment: out['1'] will print what's depicted in line 1; so use something like ```print("linia",num,":",out[str(num)]``` Again, please check the information related to python dicts.